ERROR mocking getAllAccounts method with Jasmine and MsalService - Angular
I am facing issues with test-coverage using jasmine, for that I am working with MsalService-Entra (Microsoft Authentication Library) and Angular 15, I am using a method to get All user accounts from a list that MsalService library provides us and the idea is to create a test-coverage for that, specificaly for this line:
this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts().length 

So I tried in many ways but still I am having problems mocking that getAllAccounts method from msaservice library, this is my code that I tried and I hope you could help me with that.
login.ts
checkAndSetActiveAccount() {
    if (this.msalService.instance && this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
        const accounts = this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts();

This is my login.spec.ts
    let msalServiceMock: jasmine.SpyObj<MsalService>;    
    
    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
            msalServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('MsalService', ['instance', 'getAllAccounts']);

        TestBed.resetTestingModule();
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
                    [{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}]
                ),
            ],
            providers: [
                {provide: MsalService, useValue: msalServiceMock}
            ],
            declarations: [LoginComponent]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));
...

    it('checkAndSetActiveAccount() check and validate Active Account', ()=> {

        let mockAccounts =[
            { homeAccountId: '', environment:'', tenantId:'', username:'', localAccountId:'' }
        ];

        //msalServiceMock = TestBed.inject(MsalService);
        //mockMsalService.instance.setActiveAccount(mockData[0]);
        //spyOn(msalServiceMock, 'instance').and.returnValue(mockAccounts);
        spyOn(msalServiceMock.instance, 'getAllAccounts').and.returnValue(mockAccounts);
        //spyOn(component.msalService.instance, 'getAllAccounts').and.returnValue(of(mockData));
        component.checkAndSetActiveAccount();

Error on console:
Firefox 132.0 (Mac OS 10.15) LoginComponent processCredentials() is processing username and password checkAndSetActiveAccount() check and validate Active Account FAILED
    Error: <spyOn> : getAllAccounts() method does not exist
    Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>) in node_modules/karma-jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js (line 9619)
    <Jasmine>

Firefox 132.0 (Mac OS 10.15) LoginComponent processCredentials() is processing username and password username and password are empty strings FAILED
        TypeError: this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts is not a function in main.js (line 98918)


I have not implemented the exact MsalService, but I have mocked the service  to solve the test case.
We use createSpyObj to mock the methods and the properties of the service. I set instance as null so that it can be set on the test case.
  msalServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('MsalService', ['getAllAccounts'], {
    instance: null,
  });

I use `` to set the return value for the property instance and set it to the scope of the same service, this is only for testing purposes. Due to typing issue I had to wrap it inside a as any block.
  (
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(msalServiceMock, 'instance').get as any
  ).and.returnValue(component.msalService);

Then we can spy on the method and perform the checks.
it('checkAndSetActiveAccount() check and validate Active Account', () => {
  let mockAccounts = [
    {
      homeAccountId: '',
      environment: '',
      tenantId: '',
      username: '',
      localAccountId: '',
    },
  ];
  (
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(msalServiceMock, 'instance').get as any
  ).and.returnValue(component.msalService);
  msalServiceMock.getAllAccounts.and.returnValue(mockAccounts as any);
  component.checkAndSetActiveAccount();
  expect(msalServiceMock.getAllAccounts).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.data).toEqual(mockAccounts);
});

Full Code:
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent, MsalService } from './app.component';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let msalServiceMock: jasmine.SpyObj<MsalService>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    msalServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('MsalService', ['getAllAccounts'], {
      instance: null,
    });

    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        // RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
        // { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        // ]),
      ],
      providers: [{ provide: MsalService, useValue: msalServiceMock }],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('checkAndSetActiveAccount() check and validate Active Account', () => {
    let mockAccounts = [
      {
        homeAccountId: '',
        environment: '',
        tenantId: '',
        username: '',
        localAccountId: '',
      },
    ];
    (
      Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(msalServiceMock, 'instance').get as any
    ).and.returnValue(component.msalService);
    msalServiceMock.getAllAccounts.and.returnValue(mockAccounts as any);
    component.checkAndSetActiveAccount();
    expect(msalServiceMock.getAllAccounts).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.data).toEqual(mockAccounts);
  });
});

Stackblitz Demo

yeah very helpfully, thanks so much for that
